# can't find runtime.js in pug folder

Tags: pug, jade4j

as official tutorial said:

> Be sure to send the Pug runtime (node_modules/pug/runtime.js) to the client in addition to the template that you just compiled.

but actually cannot find out in node_modules/pug folder. 
in addition, i searched each sub-folders and each files, still no.
can anyone help on this?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some parts of the official documentation and tutorials haven't been updated in a while. This issue however has been discussed over at the projects GitHub repository. You can read through it here:

[runtime.js not existing. #2547](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2547)

Comment: Hi @sunny-sun if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When you install pug via `"npm i --save pug"` then in `node_modules` folder some folder are added which are related to pug. At that time a folder named `node_modules/regenerator-runtime` is also added. You can find `runtime.js` at that folder.